# How does LevelDB handle sequence number in bloom filter?

Tags: database, key-value-store, leveldb, rocksdb, bloom-filter

I have read the source code of `LevelDB`. I found that it uses internal key when calling `AddKey()` of filter_block. If we call `Get()` later, it will construct a lookup key using the last sequence number, and the key will be passed to function `KeyMayMatch()`. But the last sequence number is different from the sequence number used in `AddKey()`, so why can bloom filter return the right result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In RocksDB, to create bloom you have to specify the number of bytes per key to be added to bloom. Although the Internal key is a combination of user key and sequenceNumber, the latter will be stripped off while creating filter. The sequence number will not be a part of the key used to construct the bloom.
So when you call `Get()` the given key is passed to `KeyMayMatch()`, if the bloom filter results true, then rocksdb scans the files to fetch the key (if it is present. Remember bloom filter can give false positives). If the bloom results false, the key is not present in the DB.

Answer (score 0):

No. It's incorrect that *it uses internal key when calling AddKey() of filter_block*.
There is a wrapper class called InternalFilterPolicy above the BloomFilterPolicy, which extracts the "user-key" from the internal-key and passes to BloomFilterPolicy when create filter or test key match.